# Group rows in Vuetify Data Table body

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

In the body section of a v-data-table, where Vuetify puts the items, it wraps all of the rows in a tbody tag. My slot template consists of multiple rows all which I need to group so that I can apply transitions or other effects.

How can I make v-data-table stop wrapping the body in a tbody tag, resulting in nested tbody tags?

```
  <v-data-table
    ref="dataTable"
    :headers="headers"
    fixed-header
    :height="height"
    :items="invoices"
    item-key="id"
    :search="search"
    class="elevation-1"
    disable-pagination
    :loading="loading"
    loading-text="Loading invoices... please wait..."
    :no-data-text="this.noDataText"
    no-results-text="No invoices found for your search."
    :hide-default-footer="true"
  >
    <template v-slot:headers="props">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th
            v-for="header in props.headers"
            :key="header.text"
            ref="dataTableHdr"
            :class="['column sortable', pagination.descending ? 'desc' : 'asc', header.value === pagination.sortBy ? 'active' : '', header.class === '']"
            @click="changeSort(header.value)"
          >
            <v-icon small>arrow_upward</v-icon>
            {{ header.text }}
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </template>

    <template v-slot:item="props">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>{{ props.item.vendorCode }}</td>
          <td>CONTENT</td>
          <td>CONTENT</td>
          <td>CONTENT</td>
          <td>CONTENT</td>
          <td>CONTENT</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>{{ props.item.vendorName }}</td>
          <td>CONTENT</td>
          <td>CONTENT</td>
          <td>CONTENT</td>
          <td>CONTENT</td>
          <td>CONTENT</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can omit the `tbody` from the template since v-data-table puts the `tbody` around the results already when using `v-slot:item`.

```
<template v-slot:item="props">

    <tr>
      <td>{{ props.item.vendorCode }}</td>
      <td>CONTENT</td>
      <td>CONTENT</td>
      <td>CONTENT</td>
      <td>CONTENT</td>
      <td>CONTENT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>{{ props.item.vendorName }}</td>
      <td>CONTENT</td>
      <td>CONTENT</td>
      <td>CONTENT</td>
      <td>CONTENT</td>
      <td>CONTENT</td>
    </tr>

</template>
```

Comment: But then all you get is a single tbody element. I need to group the multiple rows of each output item so that I can apply a transition to them.  My goal is to provide better feedback when one is removed from the items array.  Default behavior is just poof, they are gone. If the one below looks similar it almost looks like nothing happened. I need it to be more obvious that you just deleted the item.